# Update location of form when changing screen resolution

Tags: c#, screen, resolution

Can anyone tell me how to make my application (c#) adjust to the screen resolution so it always stays in center screen?

Answer (score 0):

If you're using MS Visual Studio, there is a property called "StartPosition" in your form's properties window. Set it to "CenterScreen".

Comment: Yes Im using VS and i have already set StartPosition to CenterScreen and it works perfect when i start the application. But if the application is running and the user change resolution from for example 1920*1080 to 1024*768 the application doens't stay in the center.

Comment: but if you close it and open again?
it will not stay because it's just the start position :D

Comment: The user should not be able to close the application, controlbox is disable so i need that the applications updates it position when screen resolution is changed. :S